# Calculate $\sum _{k=1}^n\:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ 4k-1\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

$\sum _{k=1}^n\:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ 4k-1\end{pmatrix}$

My general idea:

$\sum _{k=1}^n\:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ 4k-1\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\sum _{k=1}^n\:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ \:4k-1\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{2}\sum \:_{k=1}^n\:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ \:4\left(n-k-1\right)-1\end{pmatrix}=
$

$\frac{1}{2}\sum \:_{k=1}^{2n}\:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ \:\:2k-1\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum \:\:_{k=1}^{2n}\:\begin{pmatrix}4n-1\\ \:\:\:2k-1\end{pmatrix}-\sum \:\:\:_{k=1}^{2n}\:\begin{pmatrix}4n-1\\ \:\:\:\:2k-2\end{pmatrix}\right)=$

$\frac{1}{2}\sum \:\:\:_{k=1}^{4n}\:\begin{pmatrix}4n-1\\ \:\:k-1\end{pmatrix}=2^{4n-2}$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to apply a discrete Fourier transform. We have that $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$ f(n) = \frac{1^n + i^n + (-1)^n + (-i)^n}{4} $$
is the indicator function of the integer that are multiples of $4$, hence
$$ g(n) = \frac{1^n+ i\cdot i^n-(-1)^n-i\cdot(-i)^n}{4} $$
is the indicator function of the integers of the form $4k-1$, and

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{4n}{4k-1} = \sum_{h=0}^{4n}\binom{4n}{h}g(h) = \frac{1}{4}\left[2^{4n}+i(1+i)^{4n}-i(1-i)^{4n}\right]=\color{red}{2^{4n-2}} $$
by the binomial theorem.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you did, but thanks for the solution.

Comment: The idea is to write $\sum _{k=1}^n\:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ 4k-1\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{j=0}^{4n} \:\begin{pmatrix}4n\\ j\end{pmatrix}\mathbb{I}[j\equiv 1 \mod 4] $, and then be a bit crafty in rewriting the indicator at the end.